# Restore xorg.conf file in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: xorg, gpu-driver, vga, xorg.conf

Checking the content of /etc/X11 dir, I saw that xorg.conf file is missing. Is that normal? I only have xorg.conf.failsafe configuration file with the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Is, the one above, a correct configuration file? Or, I have to restore the xorg.conf file? If yes, how can I do that? The current driver used is:

```
sudo lshw -c display | grep driver
[sudo] password di michele: 
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

and

```
lspci | grep -E 'VGA|Display|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT] (rev ff)
```

A few hours ago, after rebooting my OS, I got a black screen with message:

> your system is running in low-graphics mode

but after restarting the pc, all strangely returned as before.

Thanks!

Comment: So, no more needed the xorg.conf file. Well, if the screen with message "your system is running in low-graphics mode" should appears again, what should I do?

Comment: As you can see from the duplicate, xorg.cong is not needed by most users. From the accepted answer, however, "The xorg.conf does not exist by default any more. `You CAN create one though.`" Some users may desire or need to use a custom xorg.conf to configure options (refresh rate is probably most common) or hardware (touchpad is probably most common here). A better question is, what problem are you having with X and what makes you feel you need an xorg.conf ? If it is not broken, don't fix it.

Comment: Well, the problem I encountered was about the message I got after booting my system "your system is running in low-graphics mode". Reading something in internet, I figured out that the first thing to check was the xorg.conf file. That's all. I am afraid it will occour again after a reboot, but I am not sure.